# how to filter rows in promtail yaml config

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I'm a bit new to Grafana so this might be an easy one!  I have a simple config-promtail.yaml file loading logs into Loki and everything is working, but I'd like to restrict the log rows passed to Loki to only those lines that include the word "error".  Here is what I have:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: <port #>
  grpc_listen_port: <port #>

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: 'http://10.128.15.231:3100/loki/api/v1/push'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: system
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - localhost
        labels:
          job: log_export
          __path__: /path/to/log/file.log
          host: host-name
    pipeline_stages:
      - match:
          selector: '{host="host-name"} |= "error"'
          action: keep
```

it works fine until I add the |= "error
I've also tried something like this:

```
pipeline_stages:
  - match:
      selector: '{host="host-name"}'
      stages:
      - regex:
        expression: '.*error.*'
```

which also throws config errors. it seems like this should be relatively simple, but the documentation is really not clear...thanks in advance for any assistance!